# Cant create object of type unorderedLinkedList

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

I have two `.h` files, the base class which is `linkedListType` and the derived class `unorderedLinkedList`. For some reason, it wont let me create an object from my `unorderedLinkedList` class. I'm also using templates throughout my program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "unorderedLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unorderedLinkedList<int> list, subList;

    int num;

    cout << "Enter numbers ending with -999" << endl;
    cin >> num;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#define UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
#ifndef UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
#include "linkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//creates class type unorderedLinkedList
template <class Type>
class unorderedLinkedList : public linkedListType<Type>
{
public:
    bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;
    //function to determine wether searchItem is in the list
    void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#define LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
#ifndef LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class linkedListType
{
public:
    void divideMid(linkedListType<Type>& sublist);
    // divide list
    const linkedListType<Type>& operator=(const linkedListType<type>&);
    // overload the assignment operator.
    void initializeList();
};

#endif
```

Comment: You first `#define UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H`, and **then** check whether it's undefined. Of course it is in fact defined - you've just defined it yourself a line above. Whereupon the whole header is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your header files, your `#define` and `#ifndef` statements are in the wrong order.

In each file, you are defining the guard value and then checking if it is defined, which it is, so the entire content of the header file is skipped.

You need to define the guard value only if it is not already defined:

```cpp
#ifndef UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
#define UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
...
#endif
```

```cpp
#ifndef LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
#define LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to check if the include guard is defined before defining it otherwise it will never include in the first place.

Also you should use either #pragma once (if supported) or the #ifndef #define guards. It is not necessary to use both.

Again, to reiterate

-remove the #pragma once

-change the order of your ifndef / define

```cpp
    #ifndef UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
    #define UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
    ...
    #endif

    #ifndef LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
    #define LINKEDLISTTYPE_H
    ...
    #endif
```